# How to add module image in custom module backend configuration?

Tags: magento2.4.3

how to add custom image or icon like below reference picture in custom module configuration from backend in Magento 2.4.3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create system.xml as usual, add tab as usual and add to tab class, something like this

```
<tab id="tab_id" sortOrder="1" translate="label" class="yourmodule-tab">
```

I am not good at css, but do something like this. Create in your module file view/adminhtml/web/css/source/_module.less and add

```
.config-nav .yourmodule-tab .admin__page-nav-title:before {
    content: '';
    background: url("URL_HERE_OR_SVG") no-repeat 0 0;background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
}
.config-nav .yourmodule-tab .admin__page-nav-title strong {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Create Menu app/code/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_HelloWorld::helloworld" title="Hello World" module="Vendor_HelloWorld" sortOrder="51" resource="Vendor_HelloWorld::helloworld"/>
        <add id="Vendor_HelloWorld::post" title="Manage Posts" module="Vendor_HelloWorld" sortOrder="10" action="vendor_helloworld/post" resource="Vendor_HelloWorld::post" parent="Vendor_HelloWorld::helloworld"/>
        <add id="Vendor_HelloWorld::hello_configuration" title="Configuration" module="Vendor_HelloWorld" sortOrder="99" parent="Vendor_HelloWorld::helloworld" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/helloworld" resource="Vendor_HelloWorld::helloworld_configuration"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

2)Create app/code/Vendor/HelloWorld/view/adminhtml/web/css/helloworld.css

```
.admin__menu .level-0.item-helloworld > a:before {
    content: url('../images/image.svg');
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30px;
}
```

3)Upload your icon to app/code/Vendor/HelloWorld/view/adminhtml/web/images/
4)Create app/code/Vendor/HelloWorld/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_HelloWorld::css/helloworld.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

5)Run following commands

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area adminhtml

php bin/magento cache:clean